# Why is apk generated by studio smaller than command line apk

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk

OS : Mac os

Gradle 3.0

APK generated by studio : 13 Mb

APK generated by command line using "gradle assembleDebug" : 21 Mb.

Its almost double the size for the same project with the same build.gradle file.

I have used

```
aaptOptions
{
    cruncherEnabled = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Any idea if there are parameters being passed specifically by Studio which help reduce the size?

Comment: I think `minifyEnabled true` is doing the magic

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, does the command line gradle not read the same build.gradle which has the minifyEnabled true?

Comment: can someone explain why I am getting downvotes instead of only downvoting the question? Is this how people who do not have information are treated? Makes me think why did I ask the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build APK in Android studio connecting the phone, then Android studio removes all the resources from your drawable folder which is not applicable to that phone. That's the reason APK generated by Android studio looks smaller.

Try this, connect different resolution phone, HDPI, MDPI, XXHDPI phones while building your APK. You can find different size of APKs generated